# Is there a way to pass an String Array as Variable for the server sided Xquery script?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xquery, marklogic

Im trying to improve the Search of my Spring-Boot Services by implementing a server-sided xquery search which is triggered by java invokation

I tried some stuff with loops but it didnt work

....

```
protected DatabaseClient databaseClient;

public DocumentDTO searchDocument(String language, String documentId, String... culsterIds) throws JAXBException {
        ServerEvaluationCall invoker = databaseClient.newServerEval();
      invoker.modulePath("/main/searchForDocuments.xqy")
                .addVariable("language", language)
                .addVariable("documentId", documentId)
                .addVariable("clusterIds", consentTemplateIds);
....
```

the variables should be inserted in the xqy script to get the corresponding
search result for the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As you've determined, addVariable() only takes single values.

You could serialize the list of values as a JSON array and send the JSON array using a JSONWriteHandle.  Then, in XQuery, use xdmp:from-json() to convert the JSON array node to an in-memory array.

Or, if you're using a recent version of MarkLogic 9, you could use a Data Service to produce a client interface specify to your endpoint module:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/DataServices

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thank you very much, I think i will go with the first approach, because the Data Service approach seems kind of extensive. Or maybe even with the way of passing them all as a single string, seperated by a komma and use the tokenize function in xquery. Thanks a lot though !

Comment: Sorry for the late Answer, thanks a lot for your help. Anyway ive chosen a more simple way: Im giving the Method a List of Strings as a parameter, make it to a single string, pass it to the xquery script where i split it to a sequence again.